# Get label percentages from Google Vision API

Tags: c#, google-cloud-vision

I would like to use the Google Vision API for label detection. For this I am using a .NET library. This is my code:

```
        var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
        // Load the image file into memory
        var image = Image.FromFile("trui3.jpg");
        // Performs label detection on the image file
        var response = client.DetectLabels(image);
        foreach (var annotation in response)
        {
            if (annotation.Description != null)
                Console.WriteLine(annotation.Description);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

It works very well. It displays all the labels. But on the Google [website](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) it also displays the percentages of the labels. See the image for an example.

How can I achieve this by using the .NET library?

[image: Vision API from Google website.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotations have a `Score` (see further down the [C# example page](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-labels#vision-label-detection-gcs-csharp)), which falls in the [0,1] range.

```
if (annotation.Description != null)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"{annotation.Description} ({annotation.Score}");
}
```